# WebBrowser - check result of execCommand

Tags: c#, .net, mshtml

I use WebBrowser:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser.Document;
IHTMLTxtRange range = (IHTMLTxtRange)doc.selection.createRange();
...
if(range.execCommand("StrikeThrough", false, null))
{
    //Is range strikethroughed or not?
}
```

How can i detect is selection strike-through or not (in code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it has been 3 years, but I think for anyone searching:

Try using

```
bool struckthrough = doc.queryCommandState("StrikeThrough");
```

It returns `true` / `false` if the current selection has that markup.  You are creating a range object - You can `range.select()` to set that as your range to be checked by the query state.

Comment: I can't check this solution so will assume, that it solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a mshtml-based editor in c++ a while ago, and I did something like the following code to get the text style of the current selection.

```
CComQIPtr<IOleCommandTarget> spCmdTarg(pDispDoc);

if (pStyle && spCmdTarg)
{
    const ULONG uNumCmnds = 4;
    OLECMD arrCmnds[uNumCmnds];
    arrCmnds[0].cmdID = IDM_BOLD;
    arrCmnds[1].cmdID = IDM_ITALIC;
    arrCmnds[2].cmdID = IDM_UNDERLINE;
    arrCmnds[3].cmdID = IDM_STRIKETHROUGH;

    if ( SUCCEEDED(spCmdTarg->QueryStatus(&CGID_MSHTML, uNumCmnds, arrCmnds, NULL)) )
    {
        pStyle->SetBold(arrCmnds[0].cmdf & Shdocvw_tlb::OLECMDF_LATCHED);
        pStyle->SetItalic(arrCmnds[1].cmdf & Shdocvw_tlb::OLECMDF_LATCHED);
        pStyle->SetUnderline(arrCmnds[2].cmdf & Shdocvw_tlb::OLECMDF_LATCHED);
        pStyle->SetStrikeThrough(arrCmnds[3].cmdf & Shdocvw_tlb::OLECMDF_LATCHED);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how this code can be translated in c# and what's available on the interlop layer of mshtml, but hopefully this can help you get started on somewhere.

Comment: You set some properties. I also can do it. I can't get properties of selection (GetStrikeThrough is disappear).

Answer (score 0):

The execCommand returns true if the command is successful. So you could try:

```
if (range.execCommand("StrikeThrough", false, null))
{
    // Strikethrough succeeded
}
```

To determine if the selection is already StrikeThrough, you could look at the parentElement property of the text range object and see if it is a strike element.

Comment: I need in result: is text strike-through or not.